# how to format xml into soap response format?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I need to format an xml into a soap1.1 response envelope.

First, my business objects. I am aware of the insane nesting. I am not allowed to change the structure:

```
    [DataContract]  
    public class DIVSReturnObject  
    {  
        public CoverageResponseDocument coverageResponseDoc { get; set; }  
        public DIVSReturnObject()  
        {  
            coverageResponseDoc = new CoverageResponseDocument();
        }  
    }  

    [DataContract]  
    public class CoverageResponseDocument  
    {
         public Detail detail { get; set; }

         public CoverageResponseDocument()
         {
             detail = new Detail();
         }
    }  
    [DataContract]
    public class Detail
    {
        public PolicyInformation policyInformation { get; set; }
        public VehileInformation vehicleInformation { get; set; }

        public Detail()
        {
            policyInformation = new PolicyInformation();
        }
     }  

    [DataContract]
    public class PolicyInformation
    {
        public OrganizationDetails organizationDetails { get; set; }
        public PolicyDetails policyDetails { get; set; }
        public CoverageStatus coverageStatus { get; set; }

        public PolicyInformation()
        {
            coverageStatus = new CoverageStatus();
        }
    }  

    [DataContract]
    public class CoverageStatus
    {
        public ResponseDetails responseDetails { get; set; }

        public CoverageStatus()
        {
            responseDetails = new ResponseDetails();
        }
    }  

    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseDetails
    {
        [DataMember]
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ResponseCode")]
        public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "UnconfirmedReasonCode")]
        public string UnconfirmedReasonCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Next, my code to serialize the desired object to XML:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();  
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(divsResponse.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, divsResponse);
        xmlStream.Position = 0;

        xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
        return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
    }
```

Next, the resulting XML string. Note that ResponseCode and UnconfirmedReasonCode are attributes when they should be their own elements:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <DIVSReturnObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <coverageResponseDoc>
            <detail>
                <policyInformation>
                    <coverageStatus>
                        <responseDetails ResponseCode="Unconfirmed" UnconfirmedReasonCode="VIN1" />
                    </coverageStatus>
                </policyInformation>
            </detail>
        </coverageResponseDoc>
    </DIVSReturnObject>
```

Finally, the desired envelope with the correct namespaces (how do I add those?):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">  
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>  
            <CoverageResponseDocument PublicationVersion="00200809" PublicationDate="2008-11-05" xmlns="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/">  
                <Detail>  
                    <PolicyInformation>  
                        <CoverageStatus>  
                            <ResponseDetails>  
                                <ResponseCode>Unconfirmed</ResponseCode>  
                                <UnconfirmedReasonCode>VIN1</UnconfirmedReasonCode>  
                            </ResponseDetails>  
                        </CoverageStatus>  
                        <OrganizationDetails>   
                            <NAIC>12345</NAIC>  
                            <!-- this can be echoed from the request or provide the actual NAIC that has evidence of coverage -->  
                        </OrganizationDetails>  
                        <PolicyDetails>  
                            <!-- this section can be echoed from the request -->  
                            <VerificationDate>2015-01-01T00:00:00.000</VerificationDate>  
                            <PolicyKey>UNKNOWN</PolicyKey>  
                            <PolicyState>CT</PolicyState>  
                        </PolicyDetails>  
                    </PolicyInformation>  
                </Detail>  
            </CoverageResponseDocument>  
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>  
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you look for answers along: "Use XSLT or Text Templating" or do you look for answers related to "How to change my code so an attribute becomes an element"?

Comment: I am looking for answers along changing my code to generate the soap format at the bottom. I will research the formatting on my own if it is not handled by the correct solution for the soap response.

Comment: ``[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ResponseCode")]`` This is basically the line which makes the ResponseCode an attribute. If you can change it to an element, one problem solved ;)

Comment: All in all, there too many possiblities in your situation - kind of hard to find a short and concise answer. One radical approach would be to use the wsdl contract definition and generate your C# object model from it. Same could work on XML level with xsd tool. Next, you could write an XSLT to transform the xml you get from the DOM to the DOM you need. Next, you could use tttt (text templating c# facility) and "fill in" your response with data drawn from the DOM, ... and many many more.

Comment: For your reading pleasure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674270(v=vs.110).aspx - Contract first workflow to get the code generated from the contract.

Comment: Since I am new to this I might not be asking the right question. Which solution will allow me to handle this in code without involving other tools to massage the string? Since my response will  be a static single structure is it OK to use string builder to create this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445(v=vs.120).aspx <-- Better way than doing stringbuilder code by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the following conditions which I hope apply in your case, there is indeed a pretty quick way to solve your problems. And time is money, right?

- Soap response is rather static (no collection etc. Just a hand full of fields to fill in).
- You do not have full control over your code base (DOM) and as such look to decouple your solution somewhat from the DOM code. With DOM I mean the data model classes you showed in your question.

The drawbacks of the solution I show below are:

- Not a "generic" solution which should be applied in all situations. (suits your current problem but maybe not your next ones).
- As cool as text templating is, there is one source of possible errors, once things get more complicated (dynamic) - it is hard to proof that you will produce the correct output at all times. Maybe then, other solutions such as a reviewable xslt transform or even better a "contract first -> code generating of the DOM" appraoch is more reliable.

I suggest you warm yourself up a little before you add this to your main project. A small C# console application project will do.

1. Create your toy console app (File-> New Project -> C# -> ConsoleApp).
2. Right click your project in solution explore and Add New Item -> Runtime Text Template. It is important to use "Runtime Text Template" and not "Text Template" in your case. Give it a proper name (I used in my demo code "MySoapResponse.tt".
3. In the generated .tt file which is now part of your project items, copy and paste the desired soap output below what is already contained in the file.
4. Create yourself a dummy DOM just to have the same scenario as you have it in your application.
5. Add a new C# code file to your project and add a partical class in the same namespace as the code-behind .tt code uses, with the name of the generated template class (which is partial). Add a constructor where you pass as argument the instance of your DOM which you want to use for generating the message.
6. Create a few Query functions or simply a Document {get;} property.
7. In your console app main, create an instance of your DOM with some data in it.
8. Also create an instance of your generated generator object.
9. Call the `TransformText()` method and save the string to a file on your disk for inspection.

   10. Rince and repeat: Modify your .tt template by adding more and more markdown statements at the spots where you need the data from your DOM.

As you can see - 10 steps and you are done.

This is how the transformation code looks like (even simpler than XmlSerializer calls):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDOM.Root document = MyDOM.Root.CreateExampleDocument();
            MySoapResponse responseGenerator = new MySoapResponse(document);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\temp\blabla.txt", responseGenerator.TransformText());

            System.Console.WriteLine("Done transforming!");

        }
    }
}
```

And this - just for completness sake is my miniDOM I invented for this answer:

```
namespace MyDOM
{
    internal class Root
    {
        internal ChildA childA { get; set; }
        internal ChildB childB { get; set; }

        internal static Root CreateExampleDocument()
        {
            Root r = new Root();
            r.childA = new ChildA();
            r.childB = new ChildB();
            r.childA.ResponseCode = "I have my reasons!";
            r.childA.ReasonCode = "I have response code using T4!";
            return r;
        }
    }

    internal class ChildA
    {
        internal string ResponseCode { get; set; }
        internal string ReasonCode { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ChildB
    {

    }
}
```

I only added 2 items - which is sufficient to showcase how it all works.

In the .tt file of course, I also added just enough to cover those 2 items.

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">  
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>  
            <CoverageResponseDocument PublicationVersion="00200809" PublicationDate="2008-11-05" xmlns="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/">  
                <Detail>  
                    <PolicyInformation>  
                        <CoverageStatus>  
                            <ResponseDetails>  
                                <ResponseCode><#=ResponseCode()#></ResponseCode>  
                                <UnconfirmedReasonCode><#=ReasonCode()#></UnconfirmedReasonCode>  
                            </ResponseDetails>  
                        </CoverageStatus>  
                        <OrganizationDetails>   
                            <NAIC>12345</NAIC>  
                            <!-- this can be echoed from the request or provide the actual NAIC that has evidence of coverage -->  
                        </OrganizationDetails>  
                        <PolicyDetails>  
                            <!-- this section can be echoed from the request -->  
                            <VerificationDate>2015-01-01T00:00:00.000</VerificationDate>  
                            <PolicyKey>UNKNOWN</PolicyKey>  
                            <PolicyState>CT</PolicyState>  
                        </PolicyDetails>  
                    </PolicyInformation>  
                </Detail>  
            </CoverageResponseDocument>  
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>  
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The calls I invoke from within the .tt template (e.g. `<#=ResponseCode()`) are methods I added to my partial class part of the generator object.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public partial class MySoapResponse
    {
        MyDOM.Root Document { get; }
        internal MySoapResponse(MyDOM.Root document)
        {
            Document = document;
        }
        internal string ResponseCode()
        {
            return Document.childA.ResponseCode;
        }
        internal string ReasonCode()
        {
            return Document.childA.ReasonCode;
        }
    }
}
```

And that is about it. A bit of clicking and a few lines of code actually written (let it be 50 lines). For sure better than using a StringBuilder by hand.

Comment: it took me a little time to wrap my head around how this is put together but it works. Thank you sir!